# Link outside of an Iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, hyperlink

I have links within an iframe that are external, and I would like them to open in the same window, leaving the iframe.
Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want to specify `target="_top"` like so:

```
<a href="http://example.com/" target="_top">Click me!</a>
```